# How to get back from tabbar view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

My Initial screen is `HomeViewController`, from `HomeViewController` I am move to `TabBarViewController`. Now, I want to move back to `HomeViewController`. I am using following code for that:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Can you show how you are adding `tabBarController` from `HomeViewController`? Most probably you can do `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = HomeViewController()`

Comment: I am using button for navigation from HomeViewController to Tabbar ViewController @Kamran

Comment: How are you moving from HomeViewController to Tab Controller? Are you using navigation controller to push your Tabbar ViewController?

Comment: Have you initialize your HomeViewController with NavigationController?

Comment: yes i  initialize HomeViewController with NavigationController

Answer (score 0):

Yah, It's not working, as well as `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` not working so you can push to HomeViewController from TabBarViewController.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: It works, but navigation items are missing after i comeback from another view controller

Answer (score 0):

How to get back from tabbar controller depends on how you got to it in the first plase.

If you pushed it into navigation stack, you need to call `popViewController(animated:)`. This is clearly not your case.

You could've presented it modally. Then you need to `dismiss(animated:, completion:)`.

If you set the tabbar controller as the window's root, then you need to reset the root with your `HomeViewController`. E.g.

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should custom a UITabBarViewController

When you want go to TabBarVC from Home, you push a navigation has root is a TabBarViewController. 
At TabBarViewController, if you want to back to Home, call popToViewController method of nagicationVC.

Ex:

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBAction func goToTabBarVC(_ sender: Any) {
    let tabBar = TabBarVC() 
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  tabBar)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(navigation, animated: true)
}
```

}

class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

```
@IBAction func backToHome(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: I only given a idea, it not enough code to compile success. You must  add some code,   ex HomeViewController is child of a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

In the app delegate file put following code in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

```
let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC = [st initializeViewControllerWithIdentifier:"HomeVC"]

let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  homeVC)
self.window??.rootViewController = navigation
```

or

You can directly embed the Navigation controller to the home view controller from storyboard.

Thanks